# Javascript Static Resource Cannot Be Found

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I added a javascript static resource to a folder called VisualForceElements like so:

[image]

Then within my opening `<apex:page>` I make the call to reference the resource like so:

`<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.LookupJS}"/>`

But unfortunately I keep getting this error:

**`Error: Static Resource named LookupJS does not exist. Check spelling`**

I tried also including the folder name like so:

`<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.VisualForceElementsLookupJS}"/>`

but that didn't work either. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: `Document` is not the same thing as `Static Resource`.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Long day? Perhaps someone else new to SF will make the same stupid mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to upload it as a Static Resource under Setup -> Develop -> Static Resources. You're inserting it as a Document object currently :)